# Github GraphQL: see breakdown of results by multiple authors when using search(...)

Tags: github, graphql

I'm trying to construct a GraphQL query on multiple authors (AUTHOR1, AUTHOR2 in this example).
I see how I would get a total of all PRs, but is there a way to see a breakdown by author as well?

```
query listCommitCounts($queryString: String!) {
  search(query: $queryString, type: ISSUE, first: 10) {
    issueCount
  }
}

{
  "queryString": "is:pr author:AUTHOR1 author:AUTHOR2 is:closed"
}
```

Here are the results

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "issueCount": 500
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one query (that I'm aware of) that will allow you to get an issueCount separated by user like you're asking for. You have a couple options, though:

You can make one operation, with two queries with aliases:

```
query listCommitCounts($queryString1: String!, $queryString2: String!) {
  user1:search(query: $queryString1, type: ISSUE, first: 10) {
    issueCount
  }
  user2:search(query: $queryString2, type: ISSUE, first: 10) {
    issueCount
  }
}
```

with

```json
{
  "queryString1": "is:pr author:AUTHOR1 is:closed",
  "queryString2": "is:pr author:AUTHOR2 is:closed"
}
```

which gives you:

```json
{
  "user1": {
    "search": {
      "issueCount": 100
    }
  },
  "user2": {
    "search": {
      "issueCount": 400
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can do the counting yourself by doing:

```
query listCommitCounts($queryString: String!) {
  search(query: $queryString, type: ISSUE, first: 10) {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      endCursor
    }
    edges {
      node {
        ... on PullRequest {
          author {
            login
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which will give you back the first page of results.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "pageInfo": {
        "hasNextPage": true,
        "endCursor": "Y3Vyc662OjEw"
      },
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "author": {
              "login": "AUTHOR1"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you have to take that response, count by `login`, and then look at `hasNextPage`. If it has nextPage, you can then request the next page:

```
query listCommitCounts($queryString: String!, $cursor: String!) {
  search(query: $queryString, type: ISSUE, first: 10, after: $cursor) {
    ..sameStuff
}
```

with

```json
{
  "queryString": "is:pr author:AUTHOR1 author:AUTHOR2 is:closed",
  "cursor": "Y3Vyc662OjEw"
}
```

until you get to `hasNextPage: false`.

The benefit of the former is that it's all in one call. Unfortunately, to do this programmatically, you'd have to use string interpolation to build your query, which is no fun. With the second option, it's a lot of back and forth, but you can do it with static queries.

Comment: Thank you, Dan. I wasn't aware of the 1st option, and don't mind the string building at all! Also, good to get confirmation that I wasn't missing an edge/node attribute or some such for the 2nd option.